# Is there an implied affection for Annie by Jeff in The Walk (2015)?

Tags: character, analysis, dialogue, the-walk

In the movie The Walk, there is a scene where Jeff is searching for a word to describe the wire-walking that Phillippe is about to attempt. He searches for the word in English but falls back to the French, "beau". He then looks to Annie who translates to English with a smile, "beautiful".

The movie then seems to make a clear point that Annie isn't cheating and indeed is still devoted to Phillippe when Jean-Pierre asks her (Annie) if she is going to stay out all night and wait for Phillippe to start his wire-walk. She says she will and indeed does stay there despite his suggestions that it is a rough neighborhood.

If the scene with Jeff's translation is important to the plot in some way, could it be that the film makers are implying slyly that there are other possible romances budding between the characters than the romance between Phillippe and Annie? Is there any evidence from the filmmakers as to what Jeff's scene is meant to imply or show?